# double checked locking pattern in c++ concurrent programming

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am reading concurrency programming in c++ and came across this piece of code. the book mentioned the potential for nasty race conditions.

```
void undefined_behaviour_with_double_checked_locking(){

if(!resource_ptr){        //<1>
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(resource_mutex);
    if(!resource_ptr){        //<2>   
        resource_ptr.reset(new some_resource);        //<3>
    }
}

resource_ptr->do_something();        //<4>

}
```

here is the quote of explanation from the book. however, i just cant come up with a real example. I wonder if anyone here could help me out.

> Unfortunately, this pattern is infamous for a reason: it has the
>   potential for nasty race conditions, because the read outside the lock
>   <1> isn’t synchronized with the write done by another thread inside
>   the lock <3>. This therefore creates a race condition that covers not
>   just the pointer itself but also the object pointed to; even if a
>   thread sees the pointer written by another thread, it might not see
>   the newly created instance of some_resource, resulting in the call to
>   do_something() <4> operating on incorrect values.

Comment: The quote seems to explain it pretty well... what counts as a "real example"? Are you looking for a more detailed explanation of how that code could fail?

Comment: whats confusing to me here is that in the case of two thread both calling this function, the situation seems to be fine and we would see no problem... so i wonder what the real issue is..@dlf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't show what resource_ptr is but from the explanation the reasoning seems to be that "!resource_ptr" (outside the lock) and "resource_ptr.reset" (inside the lock) are not atmoic and are not synchronized with each other.

The use case would be:

1. thread1 comes into the method, sees that resource_ptr is not
   populated, enters the lock and is in the middle of the
   resource_ptr.reset.
2. thread2 comes into the method and is when
   checking !resource_ptr may see it as set but resource_ptr may not be
   fully configured for use.
3. thread2 falls through to execute "resource_ptr->do_something()" and may see resource_ptr in an inconsistent state and bad things may happen.

Comment: In general, #2 is incorrect. `resource_ptr` should not be set until `some_resource::operator new` returns, and that expression is responsible for both allocating memory and constructing the object (and will do so before returning). See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/ for a rough description of the actions performed by a `new` statement. With compiler optimizations enabled, anything's possible.  You're more likely to see 2 threads both see `resource_ptr` as unset, allocate a new `some_resource`, and continue through the function (even though the `reset` call deletes one).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read this: http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf.

Anyway, the gist of it is: the compiler is free to reorder operations as long as they appear to be executed in the program's order *in a single threaded situation*. On top of that, some CPU architectures take the same liberties with their instruction execution order. So, technically resource_ptr could be modified to point to newly allocated memory before some_resource's constructor has finished. Another thread could at that time see that resource_ptr is not null and attempt to use the not-yet-fully-constructed instance.

The use of a smart pointer instead of a raw pointer might make this less likely, but it doesn't rule it out afaik.

Comment: Thanks to the function call, the `new` is sequenced before the execution of `reset` (which changes the pointer). Shouldn't this ensure the object is fully constructed at that point? (The situation is different from the usual case where a pointer assignment is used.)

Comment: I was wondering the same: i.e. what exact effect the use of a simple smart pointer would have on the whole. From what I can tell though, the fact that the allocation and construction are sequenced before the function call does not transcend the single-threaded situation unless atomics or synchronization objects come into play.

Answer (score 0):

The potential problem is that the write to `resource_ptr` isn't atomic (inside the `reset` call). Assuming that `resource_ptr` is a global or static variable that (/ or otherwise) starts initialized with the value NULL before we get here, it will never cause a thread to fall-through unless the object `some_resource` is already fully allocated and constructed, however - say that the pointer to this new object is 0x123456789, then it is theoretically possible that `resource_ptr` has, for example, the value `0x12340000` when another thread does the `if (!resource_ptr)` test, falls through and uses that value (especially more likely when using aliasing). If `resource_ptr` is an atomic variable then this code would be fine.

If a program can guarantee that the first time this code is called there is only one thread running (ie, the first call will be from main() before any other thread is created) then this will work fine too, because once initialized, the `if` test will just always fall through, resulting in only read accesses to `resource_ptr` while more than one thread is running. In that case you don't need the lock inside the `if` block though, and you are not allowed to ever write to `resource_ptr` *anywhere* else.